# Using FileReader to read a video file after capture on android using Phonegap

Tags: android, crash, cordova, filereader

I am facing a problem in what should have been a simple task of capturing video inside phonegap app. What I am trying to do is to start video recorder, capture a video file, get back the mediaFile and then extract the file path from it and read it using fileReader. I need the file to be in binary base64 so I am using readAsDataURL to read it.

What happens though is as follow. The video is captured correctly, the file path is read correctly. Filereader gets initiated. Then the app crash without the success alert poping up. This happened when I tried to read any file on the sdCard regardless of the video.

Here is the code snippet:

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) //video captured successfully
{
    var i=0;
    alert(mediaFiles[i].fullPath);
    alert(mediaFiles[i].size);

    fileReader = new FileReader(); 

    fileReader.onerror = function () {
        alert("failed");
    }

    fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
      alert(evt.target.result);
    }

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(mediaFiles[i].fullPath); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you shouldn't be using FileReader because that's not what it's for. You're better off trying the VideoPlayer PhoneGap plugin.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer